# Google Voice free calls on a Tablet

Tags: google-voice, sip, samsung-galaxy-player

I recently bought a small tablet - a Samsung Galaxy Player. I've been using Google Voice to text all my friends for free. However, I would like to start being able to call my friends as well, and have them be able to call me.

I see on the Play Store that there is an app called [GrooVe IP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gvoip) that allows me to do such a thing, but I would prefer not to pay $5 for this app. My goal, then, is to find a free alternative that works just as well.

I've checked out [SipDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sipdroid.sipua) - but I can't figure out how to use the dialer. I'm not entirely sure there is one. You see, there are billions of tutorials on the internet to help set up SipDroid on a "real" phone, but I only have a tablet with no calling capabilities, so I can't use the built in dialer because there isn't one. One thing I could do here is to find a third party dialer that works with SipDroid.

I have also looked at [3CX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tcx.sip.ui) for Android, but I can't figure that out either. It assumes you have a VoIP Provider, which I don't, unless I can use the Google, which would be very nice.

So, in this case I have three questions:

1. Is there a free alternative to GrooVe IP that works just as well?
2. Is there a third party dialer that works with SipDroid?
3. How do you set up 3CX with Google Voice, if possible?

I only need one of these three questions answered, not all three.

Comment: You did see that there is [GrooVe IP Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snrblabs.grooveip), no?

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I should have thought to look for something like that.

Comment: Not sure if Skype is free, but it might do what you want.